# Find out character at particular console location

Tags: c++, winapi, console

Is there any way to read a character from a specific location on the console? For example `Read_Console_Char(10, 40);`?

Comment: The answer will be mostly platform dependent ... Can you specify?

Comment: Since the accepted answer was for Windows, I added the winapi tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a standard way to do this, but in Windows environment you can do that. 

I've never read from arbitrary location, just writing to it with the use of **SetConsoleCursorPosition** and **GetStdHandle**. 
I Just looked on MSDN and there are related API's to get the contents, such as **ReadConsoleOutput**. Here is the link to it:  [ReadConsoleOutput example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685032%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). 
Hope that helps